# Spring jee:jdni throws exception with default value

Tags: java, spring, exception, jndi

I am trying to use the Spring jee namespace JNDI lookups with default values and encountering some annoying stack traces.  I'm using Spring 3.1 and tomcat 7 as my deployment environment.  Sometimes the JNDI variables may not be set in the context.xml, so I wanted to be able to use the default-value attribute of the jee:jndi tag.  The default value actually works, however it throws a stacktrace in the logs every time it goes to the default value.  Here is a snippet from the log:

```
2012-09-17 08:39:21,099 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean - JNDI lookup failed - returning specified default object instead
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    ...
2012-09-17 08:39:21,113 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'coreURL'
```

I did some debugging through the spring classes used to create this bean and saw where the NoInitialContextException is caught and that triggers it to use the default.  However, I feel that if there is a default value that this stack trace should not be printed to the logs.  Am I incorrect in this assumption?  Is there some setting that I could use to squelch this error?  Here is my spring configuration for the bean:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="coreURL" expected-type="java.lang.String" jndi-name="java:comp/env/my.prop" default-value="http://myserver.com/core"/>
```

Comment: As you can see, it is DEBUG message, not ERROR. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the LOG LEVEL for `org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean` to INFO, then you will not see this DEBUG information.

Comment: Yea, it would really help to be able to default to empty string

Answer (score 1):

For me default-value="" seems to be failing as well. You have to put a non-empty string value.